# Pyqt: How to maximize the column width in a tableview?

Tags: pyqt

Actually the title contains all information needed. Is there an easy function like tableview.resizeColumnsToContents() that allows the maximization of all column widths within the widget size? My columns are narrow so the table looks very compact.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want the columns to expand uniformly, you could also set the resize mode

```
tableview.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

In pyqt5 `setResizeMode` is no longer available. Instead, use `setSectionResizeMode` and `QHeaderView` in the `QtWidgets` module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you please tell me how to do this and enable it from having a scrollbar, so when you have more columns, it will still make the width bigger?

Comment: 2020 update: `tableview.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)` where `i` is the column index

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera the section index is optional. There are two overrides for `setSectionResizeMode`, one that [sets the mode for *all* sections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode), and the other that [sets the mode for a given index](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode-1).

Answer (score 5):

See [resizeColumnsToContents](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtableview.html#resizeColumnsToContents).

There's also a [stretchLastSection](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qheaderview.html#stretchLastSection-prop) property that can be used (see [QTableView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtableview.html#details)).

Comment: stretchLastSection, I missed that one. Thank you!

Comment: @gruenkohl Since it sounds like @Macke answered your question, you should mark his answer as accepted by clicking on the check sign.  Similarly, if the answer is good, though perhaps not the solution to your problem, you should click the up arrow to give it a vote.