# How to display a dataframe with PyQt5 using dynamic columns width

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyqt

I'm currently working on a user interface for my Python program with PyQt5 and feel a little lost. I hope you could help me.

The output of my program is a dataframe like in this example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['AAAAAAAA11111111', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
                   'B': ['BBBBBBBB11111111', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
                   'C': ['CCCCCCCC11111111', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
                   'D': ['CCCCCCCC11111111', 'xyz', 'xyz']})
```

My goal is to display this dataframe in a user interface. The columns should dynamically adapt to the size of the user interface (as in the grid layout).

Since there are already many contributions to the topic, I have already looked at some examples. Like this one for example.

```
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJEQEECZSH0

import sys
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['AAAAAAAA11111111', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
                   'B': ['BBBBBBBB11111111', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
                   'C': ['CCCCCCCC11111111', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
                   'D': ['CCCCCCCC11111111', 'xyz', 'xyz']})

class pandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = pandasModel(df)
    view = QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.resize(800, 600)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The program works, but I don't understand how I can dynamically adjust the width of the columns to the width of the user interface.

I would be very grateful for a few tips.

Comment: With "dynamically adjust" do you mean "make all columns resize to fill all available space"?

Comment: That's right.  For example, if I have four columns. If you want them to spread horizontally across the width of the window, and if I drag the window to the width, the columns should also widen.

At the moment the columns have a fixed width and if I drag the window bigger nothing changes at the columns.

Comment: @Louis  add  `view.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1)`

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyqt: How to maximize the column width in a tableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373033/pyqt-how-to-maximize-the-column-width-in-a-tableview)